# NSOutlineView -- combining multiple sources

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nsoutlineview, nstreecontroller

In my app, I have an `NSOutlineView` that gets its data from a `NSTreeController` -- which in turn gets it from the Core Data model.

What I would like to do now is to add group headings and maybe some additional rows to the outline view -- obviously things that should exist outside of the model and be part of the view. But, as much as I scratch my head over this, I can't think of any way to make the outline view display these things without modifying the underlying model, which is obviously a big no-no.

Your help is very appreciated. I feel like I am missing something obvious here...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you would do here is to write a custom `NSTreeController` subclass. Here is why this is the perfect place for the changes you want to do:

- It's not in the model, as you said.
- Has nothing to do with the view -- completely transparent.
- Basically what you want is to create displayed data out of saved data <- this is a controller's task.

Luckily, the Controller classes in Cocoa are very powerful and very simple at the same this. For you it should be enough to override the [`-arrangedObjects`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTreeController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001577-BBCGBIGF) method. Re-use the default implementation, as it does a lot of useful things like applying predicates or sorting. Here's how this could look like:

```
- (id)arrangedObjects {
  id root = [super arrangedObjects];

  // "root" is something like a NSTreeNode but not quite yet
  NSTreeNode *newRoot = [NSTreeNode treeNodeWithRepresentedObject: nil];
  [[newRoot mutableChildNodes] setArray: [root childNodes]];

  // Do your customizations here

  return newRoot;
}
```

The returned object is of the class [`NSTreeNode`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTreeNode_class/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTreeNode/descendantNodeAtIndexPath%3a) - see the documentation on how to do modifications.

Comment: Can't believe I haven't considered this approach before. One correction: `-arrangedObjects` does not return an object of the `NSTreeNode` class, but an object that handles `-childNodes` and `-descendantNodeAtIndexPath:` messages. Also, it might prove better to override `-rearrangeObjects` and do your work there.

Comment: Thanks, it seems like a step in the right direction. But NSTreeController is woefully opaque and, as Mike wrote, only returns bizarro _NSTreeProxy objects that are not derived from NSTreeNode. And that means I can't use mutableChildNodes, so I'm still investigating this.

Comment: Alright. Then just use the `-childNodes` method to get the nodes, create a separate `NSTreeNode` and return that one! (I'll adjust the answer in a second)

Comment: @Mike: `-rearrangeObjects` does barely anything else than calling `-arrangedObjects` and cache the result. The one I used in my example is probably the one to override...

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't work that easily. Reading it here, it *should* work, but the issue is the opaque `_NSTreeProxy` root node. If you return an `NSTreeNode` instead, nothing will work anymore and you'll get messages that the tree node doesn't handle a `_valueForKeyPath:ofObjectAtIndexPath:` message. So I implemented my own proxy object, an `NSTreeNode` subclass, and tried to implement that method myself. But it doesn't work. When it gets called, I don't get access to anything. My root node proxy apparently has no child nodes, because `[[self childNodes] count]` returns 0. Sometimes I hate Cocoa.

Comment: Then you might have to bite the bitter apple and program your own tree controller. It's very sad, these APIs don't work as they are supposed to ...